# Azure Data Explorer Python Sandbox initializing error

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

When using the python sandbox in Azure Data Explorer I get the following error any time I am using the Python Sandbox:

'''Error The sandboxed query was aborted due to a failure in initializing sandboxes'''

This issue started two days ago and I dont have any idea why that is happening.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/sandboxes#errors

in such cases, it's recommended to open a support ticket for your resource, via the Azure portal.